# Preserve relation with upstream elements in akka stream

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have following code sample that works fine. I want to add some changes  to preserve relation between request and responce. How can I ahieve that?
Rest api flow's materialized value is `NotUsed`. Is it possible to somehow use `Keep.both` for that?

```
// this flow is provided by some third party library that I can't change in place
val someRestApiFlow: Flow[Int, Int, NotUsed] = Flow[Int].mapAsync(10)(x => Future(x + 1))

val digits: Source[Int, NotUsed] = Source(List(1, 2, 3))

val r = digits.via(someRestApiFlow).runForeach(println)
```

Result is

```
2
3
4
```

I want result to be like

```
1 -> 2
2 -> 3
3 -> 4
```

Comment: So you can't change that first line at all? If you could, you could map from the input to a tuple of input/output. ie `(x => Future((x, x + 1)))`

Comment: Materialized value has nothing to do with what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Ren I can't change Flow because it is provided by 3rd party library.

Comment: @ViktorKlang What should I do in that case?

Comment: @kraken You need to do what Ren proposed above. Only the transformation can say what relates to what, a Flow is not a 1:1 on the element level in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a broadcast element to create 2 separate flows. The first output of broadcast goes through `someRestApiFlow`, the second output of the broadcast goes unmodified. You then zip the output of the `someRestApiFlow` with the second output of the broadcast flow. Doing that, you have both the input element and the result of its transformation through `someRestApiFlow`.

```
digits ---> broadcast --> someRestApiFlow ---> zip --> result
                     \----------------------/
```

Comment: In that case I can't be sure that they combined in proper order, can I? Because answers from REST APIs can come in any order.

Comment: You can, for example `mapAsync` (see https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.6/scala/stream/stages-overview.html#mapasync) keeps the order intact regardless of the parallelism.

Answer (score 1):

I have also encountered this kind of cases a couple of times. The only solution I have found is creating a graph using DSL and making use of `broadcast` and `zip` stages.

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Broadcast, Flow, GraphDSL, RunnableGraph, Sink, Source, Zip}
import akka.stream.{ActorMaterializer, ClosedShape}
import akka.{Done, NotUsed}

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

object Main extends App {

  implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("my-system")
  implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val graph = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder: GraphDSL.Builder[NotUsed] =>
    import GraphDSL.Implicits._
    val src: Source[Int, NotUsed] = Source(List(1, 2, 3))
    val someRestApiFlow: Flow[Int, Int, NotUsed] = Flow[Int].mapAsync(10)(x => Future(x + 1))
    val out: Sink[(Int, Int), Future[Done]] = Sink.foreach[(Int, Int)](println)

    val bcast = builder.add(Broadcast[Int](2))
    val zip = builder.add(Zip[Int, Int])


    src ~> bcast ~>                    zip.in0
           bcast ~> someRestApiFlow ~> zip.in1
                                       zip.out ~> out

    ClosedShape
  })

  graph.run()

}
```

What is being done here is we are broadcasting the input to both a zip and a custom flow, and that zip also waits for the result of that custom flow and finally merges them to send sink.

Comment: I can't change `Flow` because it is provided by 3rd party library. Please look at my comment in code. I also put it here `this flow is provided by some third party library that I can't change in place`.